# Is Greenpan safe?

Tags: equipment, pan, non-stick

We've been using this environmentally friendly non stick pan called the Green pan from Costco and I've done some research on it, but I cant seem to find anything or anyone debunking the safeness of the pan. I've heard a lot about those so-called "environmentally friendly" products being just another money grab.

Are they safe to use? Is it another Teflon? Would cast iron be better solution for pans?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've seen these pans at one of the local cookware/houseware stores as well and wondered the same thing.  The best I've been able to dig up so far is the following:

GreenPan's [official statement](http://www.green-pan.com/cookware/content.asp?Pag=1&pnav=;2;14;) about their material is:

> GreenPan™ does not use PTFE, but brings with Thermolon™ non-stick technology a healthy alternative to the market.  Thermolon™ is heat resistant up to high temperatures.  This means that GreenPan™ has an extra safety feature; if you overheat your pan, even up to 450°C/850°F, no toxic fumes will be released and the coating will not blister or peel.

Obviously I can't verify the claims about overheating and the absence of fumes or blistering/peeling, but one thing is for certain: The pans are **not** Teflon.  Instead they use a [Thermolon](http://thermolon.com/) compound, which really and truly does not use PTFE, the "harmful" compound in Teflon products.

Of course, as we all know, that doesn't mean it's safe.  This "Thermolon" stuff is brand-new to the market so there's been very little real-world testing done.  And nobody seems to know exactly what it's made of.  If you look at early sources you'll see them blathering on about it being made with "nanotechnology", but I found an interesting little tidbit on [Mother Nature Network](http://www.mnn.com/food/healthy-eating-recipes/stories/is-greenpan-cookware-really-green):

> **UPDATE:** Thermolon’s non-stick formulation is actually **not** the product of nanotechnology. It turns out that one of the company’s “over-enthusiastic” copy writers slipped that description in because it “sounded high-tech,” not because it was true.

This information seems to be confirmed at [SuperEco](http://www.supereco.com/news/2009/03/31/greenpan-cookware-safe-or-not/).  None of them cite a source, but apparently this came straight from the horse's mouth (Thermolon) - they refuted the nanotech claim themselves.

So one thing we do know about this company is that they've made at least one bald-faced lie.  That's not enough to indict them on safety terms but it certainly does cast a suspicious light on them.  The company is also in South Korea - again, not that this necessarily means anything but SK has a pretty dismal track record when it comes to safety.

It's also interesting to read some of the reviews.  I've seen several go like this on one the MNN page:

> Obviously all these great comments about the pans were from people who most likely had only these pans for a few months. They worked great for about 6 months and then every single think I cooked started to stick and burn to the pans.

Other people say they lasted for a year, two years, etc., but all seem to confirm the same basic fact: the non-stick coating wears off over time.  If it wears off, it has to go somewhere, and that somewhere is probably in your food.  Whether or not these incredibly tiny amounts of unspecified ceramic material are actually dangerous remains to be studied.

So to summarize, here's what the reality seems to be:

- **Is it Teflon?**  No, and it doesn't use any PFOA/PTFE.
- **Is it safe?**  Inconclusive.  So far there's no evidence of safety issues.
- **Is it eco-friendly?**  Given that the company is so defensive about its manufacturing process, I'm inclined to believe that their "green" claims are exaggerated at best.
- **Is it actually any good?**  Only with very light use, according to the reviews.

**ANOTHER UPDATE:** GreenPan™ appears to have added more relevant information to their new site [greenpan.us](https://www.greenpan.us/why-ceramic) since this original Q&A occurred.  They now describe their coating as "ceramic" and claim that it is a formulation that is a patented solution of sand and water:

> Thermolon is the ceramic non-stick coating used on all GreenPan non-stick cookware. It is a coating that is manufactured without PFAS, or PFOA, and does not contain any lead or cadmium. It is made from Silicon (not to be confused with silicone), basically sand, that has been transformed into a spray-able solution and then cured onto the pan in the oven.

However, this once again appears to be a bit inaccurate. [This appears to be the Thermolon Patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US7727637) (from Google's Patent database).  The patent describes the coating as containing "silane or an oligomer derived therefrom", silicone dioxide, one or more of "tourmaline, yellow ocher, sericite, amethyst, bamboo charcoal, obsidian, elvan and lava", one or more of "strontium, vanadium, zirconium, cerium, neodymium, lanthanum, barium, rubidium, cesium and gallium", and pigment. While silicon dioxide (basically sand) is one of the main components, the additional components include a lot more than *just* silicon.

Comment: Whoa! thank you for your time and effort you put it into this question! I have read about thermolon too, but again, people doesnt seem to know what they are. I guess we'll just have to wait until and see...In the mean while, I will have to do more research about other alternatives. Thank you!

Comment: It's worth noting that "normal" nonstick coating will also wear off over time, especially with heavy use. It's best to not get too attached to your nonstick pans.

Comment: That is correct, @Bob, although I think the point was that GreenPan seems to be implying that their pans are safer than Teflon, a claim which should be met with suspicion given the fact that the coating leaches off.  Also, YMMV, but my Teflon has lasted upwards of 3 years with moderate use, which seems to be better than what people are saying about the GreenPan.

Comment: For what it's worth, we were given a few of these as a gift, but after the nonstick wore off. We've switched to cast iron and a cheap teflon (expecting to need to replace it).

Comment: If you are looking for alternatives, I ditched all my nonstick for DeBuyer's mineral steel line.  They aren't super pricey, they are much better than my all clad pans at not sticking, and they last.  Downsides, they are heavy and must be cleaned and dried immediately, or they rust.  I'm not affiliated with DeBuyer in any way, just happy with their product.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it to be 'eco friendly' if I had to replace it every year for it to be useful.  I've gotten 5+ years out of a teflon pan when it was my main pan.  (calphalon ... made sure not to use metal tools, use high heat nor heat it dry).  I know people with cast iron that is decades old.

Comment: Thermolon actually is trademarked. Look it up here:http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=tess&state=4801:3knp4v.1.1 " PAINTS, VARNISHES, LACQUERS; RUST PRESERVATIVES IN THE NATURE OF A COATING; RAW NATURAL RESINS FOR USE IN THE MANUFACTURE OF RESINS AND FOR GENERAL INDUSTRIAL USE; NONSTICK COATINGS FOR COOKWARE AND PORTABLE ELECTRIC APPLIANCES" That description is at odds with the "Inorganic Ceramic Coating" description at their website: http://www.thermolon.com/html/

Comment: @D.Woods Thanks for finding additional information. I revised your summary, though, because per the patent, there's definitely more than just sand in there.

Comment: Loose silane is a rather aggressive chemical, so one can assume it is an oligomer :) Also, rubidium would have me worried just a tiny bit - intentionally using a (though very slightly) radioactive material in a coating of which some could be ingested in case of damage just doesnt sound like a responsible idea.

Comment: Silicon is a metallic looking semiconductor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon However, if you cook it in a furnace with Oxygen, you end up getting silicates, quartz, which is what normal beach sand is made of. Perhaps they mean something like that? That'd be shiney and safe. b=But now They're talking about diamond coatings?: https://tinyurl.com/yc9pnnyq This is too much change to make me happy.

Answer (score -1):

I can verify that the green pan can handle high heat. My wife accidentally left the green pan on the element on high for more than 8 hours (she left the pan on the element in the morning and then went to work and totally forgot about it). When i returned later that afternoon around 5pm, the pan was on the stove with the element on high and the pan did not melt of lose its structure. I think with a non-ceramic pan, there is good chance it would have started a fire and burned the house down. So i was grateful that the green pan could handle the heat!

Comment: While it's great that this pan didn't lose its structure, that doesn't mean that it's necessarily still safe to use. I'm not saying that it isn't safe, either, but your anecdote doesn't really answer the question.