# How hot can my Frigidaire electric induction cook top heat up to?

Tags: electric-stoves

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/99595

> Heating nonstick pans above 500°F or 260°C will burn off the nonstick coating

I own the [Frigidaire FFED3025PW 30" Drop-In Electric Range with Expandable Elements.](https://www.furnitureappliancemart.com/item/electric-range-30in-drop-in-electric-range/1811857902) I'm using nonstick pans just on the cook top, not inside the oven. Can my cook top and nonstick pan reach anywhere near 260C?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely it can get hotter than that.

Per [Reviewed](https://www.reviewed.com/ovens/features/induction-101-better-cooking-through-science):

> On average, induction cooktops reach a maximum temperature of 665.5°F

While I don't know the specifics of your model (call Frigidaire and ask), high heat is one of the reasons people buy induction ranges.  I would be very surprised if it wasn't capable of heating your pans past 260C/500F, and very quickly too.

Some induction cooktops have a "temperature" setting on each element as well as a wattage, but even if yours does, I'll warn you not to trust that temperature setting at the top of its range.  It's an estimate.

So yes, you need to be careful not to overheat your nonstick pans.  Take the usual precautions: don't heat them empty, to leave them on the heat without watching, etc.

Comment: Clearly that's excessive precision and they reach 666°F, which is hellishly hot for cooking